# FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY within subquery using Java Persistence Query Language

Tags: java, jpa, db2, jpql

I'm trying to do a bulk update of DB2 table using Java Persistence Query Language:

```
UPDATE Account  a
SET a.Status = 'r', a.Code = :code, a.Timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE ClientNumber IN  (SELECT ClientNumber FROM Account
                        WHERE a.Status = '' AND a.Type = :type 
                        ORDER BY a.Code ASC
                        FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY)
```

However, **FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY** appears not to be supported in JPQL.

What are the other alternatives exist to do this?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  For Mainframe DB2, `FETCH FIRST` in a sub-query has only been in since 9.1 (but if you're on anything older than that, you're well out of support by now), and I believe it's been in Linux/Unix/Windows for a while now.  A quick error I see is that you're missing a comma after the `:code`, before `a.Timestamp`

Comment: @galador it is supported by the database for sure...
error that I got is org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException with list of reserved words

Comment: As @JBNizet mentions, where's your `ORDER BY` clause?  Even if this would work, you're essentially getting 5 **random** rows, which can't be what you want.  Remember, SQL is inherently **unordered**, you have to tell it what you want.  Actually, the conditions in the subquery should be included in the main `WHERE` clause, to prevent updating phantom rows (dependant on lock-level).  Also, how is this a 'bulk update' if you're only updating 5 rows?  If you're _batching_ this because of transactions, use a larger row-count.

Comment: @X-Zero 5 rows is just an example for simplicity, and I actually need random accounts

Comment: Getting random rows is a **COMPLETELY** different use-case.  For one thing, you're not going to get random-enough rows (because they're going to be ordered based off some index, usually, you just don't get to pick which one).  Generate some random `ClientNumber`s application side, and run updates over them.

Comment: @X-Zero you are missing the point of the question, but I've added ORDER BY

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to execute such a query in JPQL. You'll have to use SQL.

Or you could execute the following query:

```
SELECT a FROM Account a WHERE a.Status = '' AND a.Type = :type
```

and call `setMaxResults(5)` before executing the query. You would get 5 accounts (maximum) as a result and you could change the status, the code and the timestamp of the 5 returned accounts.

I find it strange to get the 5 first rows of a query which doesn't have any `order by` clause, though.

Comment: There will be 1 select query, and 0 to 5 update queries, depending on the number of entities, and the current state of the entities. And the JPA engine could put the 5 updates in a single batch. This is the typical way of modifying a small set of entities.